# Linear algebra doubt

Tags: linear-algebra

What's is the difference between a linear span and vector space? A linear span contains all the linear combinations from a subset of the vector space. If the subset equals the vector space itself and then linear combinations are formed out of it using the same field then linear span would contain all vectors as in the vector space itself or maybe more than the number of vectors present in the vector space. Am I correct?

Comment: You have several questions with the same or similarly vague titles. You should make them specific so that one can infer more from the title alone. For instance, you could name this one the very first sentence: "What is the difference between a linear span and vector space?"

Comment: Cool! Would keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1):

A linear span is one way of specifying a vector space, and there can be multiple spans that describe the same vector space. For example,
$$\textrm{span}([1,0], [0,1]) = \textrm{span}([1,1], [-1,1])$$
both describe the same vector space, namely the 2D XY-plane. It's similar to how the same number can be written in different ways in different bases: 8 in base 10 is 1000 in base 2.

Comment: Okay. So, does that mean the number of vectors  in a linear span can never be greater than the vector space it specifies?

Comment: @user160370 No, there can be more vectors. A set of vectors that span a vector space do not have to be linearly independent, so there can be more vectors in the spanning set than dimensions. If a spanning set of vectors is linearly independent, then it is called a basis. A spanning set does have to contain at least a number of vectors equal to the dimension of the vector space.

Answer (score 0):

When $V$ is a vector space, a vector subspace of $V$ is a subset of $V$ that is also a vector space. When $S\subset V$ the linear span of $S$ is $Sp(S),$ the set of all linear combinations of finite subsets of $S.$ Clearly $Sp(S)$ is a vector space. Linear combinations of members of $S$ are linear combinations of members of $V$ and therefore belong to $V$, so $Sp(S)\subset V.$ So $Sp(S)$ is a is a vector subspace of $V,$ and may be $V$ itself. It is the smallest vector subspace of $V$ that has $S$ as  a subset, in the sense that if $V'$ is a vector subspace of $V$ and $S\subset V'$ then $S\subset Sp(S)\subset V'.$ And $Sp(S)$ is also called the vector subspace generated by $S.$